# Creating a Hash table with a tuple as a key

Tags: java

As the title says i want to create a Hash table that takes tuples of integers as keys.What i have don so far:

```
class Tuple {
      public Tuple (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
      }
      public int k;
      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = 31 * hash + this.x;
        hash = 31 * hash + this.y;
        return hash;
    }
      private int x;
      private int y;
    }



public class Class1{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       Tuple t= new Tuple (1,1);
       HashMap<Tuple, Integer> seen = new HashMap<Tuple, Integer>();
       seen.put(t,33);

       System.out.println(seen.get(t));
   }
}
```

My problem is this: I would like to acquire the value 33 only by knowing the tuple (1,1) and not actually knowing the object t.
Something like `seen.get((1,1))` and have the value 33.

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You would do

```
System.out.println(seen.get(new Tuple(1, 1));
```

The key concept is that since you override equals and hashCode **any** Tuple object that satisfies equality and hashCode equality will work as a key, and not just the `t` object.

Edit:

Note that your Tuple class also must override the `public boolean equals(Object o)` method in a correct fashion for any of this to work correctly:

```
public class Tuple {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Tuple(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = 31 * hash + this.x;
        hash = 31 * hash + this.y;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Tuple other = (Tuple) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then test with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tuple t = new Tuple(1, 1);
    Map<Tuple, Integer> seen = new HashMap<Tuple, Integer>();
    seen.put(t, 33);

    System.out.println(seen.get(t));
    System.out.println(seen.get(new Tuple(1, 1)));
}
```

Comment: This prints null,is it for sure the right way to do it?

Comment: For me it prints `33` as it should after overriding `equals`.

Comment: @leonardiz: did you override equals??

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use any **key** for the map if:

- **key** is immutable;
- **key** implements `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

In your example, you have to use `Tuple` instance. You already could know it or create the new one with known `x` and `y` (and this new instance will be absolutely the same key because all values x and y are used in `equals()` and `hashCode()` are also the same).

---

```
// It's better to make class immutable
public final class Tuple {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public static Tuple of(int x, int y) {
        // you can add internal cashe here
        return new Tuple(x, y);
    }

    private Tuple(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Tuple))
            return false;
        return x == ((Tuple)obj).x && y == ((Tuple)obj).y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
}
```

---

**Demo**

```
Map<Tuple, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(Tuple.of(1, 1), 33);
System.out.println(map.get(Tuple.of(1, 1))); // 33
```

Comment: I only can add that as `Tuple` is immutable, hash can be calculated once in constructor. Just a small performance optimization. JVM will probably optimize it anyway, but why not help it?

Comment: `hashCode()` should be very simple, therefore calculate it only once in the constructor is useless.

Comment: I agree and I want to retract my previous statement. HashMap cashes the hash code so there is little reason to do yourself. 

I just want to point out that calling `Objects.hash(x, y)` involves boxing two ints besides the call itself, nothing to worry about, but not as simple as it looks.

Comment: Thi is true, but it make real sence on performance in less than 1% of all situations,