# Memory usage of java

Tags: java

Let's say that i have a hashmap initialized like this:

```
HashMap<Tuple,String> marks = new HashMap<Tuple,String>();
```

where Tuple is a pair of integers.
In this code:

```
String z;
Tuple t1;
for(int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++){
    t1 = new Tuple (i,i);
    z = marks.get(t1); //suppose we have hashed t1 with a String in the past
     //use z in various insances 
}
```

Since Strings are immutable this creates a new String in every loop.Memory-wise would it be better to create this String and use it inside this loop multiple times or could i always use `marks.get(t1)` and not have to create this String in each loop.What i mean is this:does `marks.get(t1)` if we use it for example in `(marks.get(t1)).compareTo("aaa")` create a New String object?

Comment: Java passes objects by reference, so the string is not duplicated. The instance you passed into the HashMap is returned and the string memory is not present multiple times.

Comment: Very similar question to this one: [Memory consumption o Java datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451465/memory-consumption-o-java-datatypes).

Comment: And this one as well: [Creating a Hash table with a tuple as a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57445657/creating-a-hash-table-with-a-tuple-as-a-key/57445673#57445673)

Comment: just a note: being immutable or not does no matter here

Answer (score 0):

String objects are reused while still in the heap, so it will not increase memory consumption.

Fetching from a map is O(1), but if you need to call `marks.get(t1)` multiple times, then it's better to set it in a variable (to avoid duplicates mostly, does not help memory though).

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    Tuple t1 = new Tuple (i,i);
    String z = marks.get(t1);
    // use z #1
    // use z #2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
z=marks.get(t1);
```

z is just referencing the RAM location of the String object stored in the mark hashmap. It would only be a new String object if you created it as such, e.g:

```
z = new String(marks.get(t1));
```

as for:

```
(marks.get(t1)).compareTo("aaa")
```

What this is doing is loading the String object marks.get(t1) and comparing it to "aaa" using the compareTo method. Once that is finished, it will be removed from the stack.

When you call a method in Java, objects used will be added to the stack, and removed once the method call is done. [Here is some more information on the stack which might help.](https://stackify.com/java-heap-vs-stack/)